# How do you read every N bits?

Tags: go, binary, bit-manipulation

There's an 64 bit signed integer and I'm trying to read every 4 bits.

```
a := int64(1229782938247303441)
for i := 0; i < 16; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", byte(a) >> 4)
    a >>=  4 
}
```

The last value is 0 which should be 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `a & 0xf` to get the bottom 4 bits.

The value `0xf` has a one bit in the low four bits and zeros in all other bits.  The result of the bitwise AND expression `a & 0xf` has the low four bits from `a` and zeros in all other bits.

```
a := int64(1229782938247303441)
for i := 0; i < 16; i++ {
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", a & 0xf)
    a >>=  4 
}
```

Comment: Why `0xf` ?  Because `0xf` in this case is a value with only the bottom 4 bits set, decimal 15.  `& 0xf` masks off the rest of `a` above the bottom 4  bits, The result of  `a & 0xf` is the bits in `a` that are *also* in `0xf` - thus, a faithful representation of `a`s bottom 4 bits.  You're not really "reading every n bits".  You're operating on the whole number every time.

Comment: I thought for the OP or future readers it might augment your answer, but if you disagree, I can clean up the comment; otherwise, we can add something about the `&` to the answer.